# Confusion as to how to reference HTML code in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Here's my situation: I want to go to Yahoo's NHL site, here: http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/scoreboard?d=2013-04-01

The above link is for April's scores.

I'm trying to get my Python code to display for me the various scores of the various table rows, as well as with the names of the teams.

However, the issue is that I am not good at referencing HTML code when using xpath--I also feel like my code may actually be really wrong, too.

Here it is:

```
from xml import etree
from urllib.request import urlopen


website_score_yahoo = urlopen('http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/scoreboard?d=2013-04-01', 'r').read()
binary_data = data.encode(ascii)
result = etree.HTML(data)

for tr in result.xpath(''):
    print (result.xpath)
```

The "for tr in result.xpath(''):" is left blank in the parentheses due to the issue I listed above.

It's a lot to cover. Sorry about that.

Comment: Rather than reading it as Unicode and then encoding it as ASCII, you may want to consider opening it as `rb` (rather than `r`) so it's `bytes` in the first place.

Comment: Changing it still displays the same error I've been getting.

Comment: Right; it was a comment, not an answer. I thought it would improve your code, but it wasn't a solution to your problem.